# Tiling on 1/4" SurePly + 1/2" OSB fixed subfloor?

Tags: subfloor, tiling, porcelain, osb

I have an insulated subfloor that is ramset in a concrete foundation.

The supports for the subfloor are spaced at 16 inches.

Most of the flooring are vinyl click tiles, but the bathroom will have porcelain tiles installed.

The floor is 1/2" OSB.
I do realize 1/2 is not enough for tiles as most manufacturers recommend 5/8"

Can I add an layer of 1/4" SurePly and be good? Or is the far that SurePly can't be glued and is only stapled means it doesn't add anything to the deflection of the subfloor?

Comment: How do you have a concrete foundation and joists spaced at 16".   Huh?

Comment: @DMoore Maybe I'm not using the right word. The supports for the subfloor are spaced every 16 inches, and nailed into the concrete.

Comment: Use 1/2” cement/hardy board

Comment: Alaska Man: Thanks for the suggestion. Cement board are not  typically used where I live. But my concern would be that the transition from floating click tiles to the porcelain floor would be significant if I add 1/2"